# Vertically centre header

Tags: header-footer, positioning, geometry

I have a document with this preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, b5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ...
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    vcentering=True,
    margin=2cm,
    showframe % show how the type block is set on the page
}
% ...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{top} % header
\rhead{}
```

The text in "top" is not vertically centred. How would I vertically centre it in the 2 cm margin (preferably without calculating the appropriate centring point)?

[image]

EDIT: Looking at the docs, I don't think `vcentering` does what I thought it does. Regardless, is there a way to vertically centre the header?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You wrote, "I don't think `vcentering` does what I thought it does." Not knowing what it is that you thought, let me quote from the package's user guide: "`vcentering=true` sets auto-centering vertically and is equivalent to `vmarginratio=1:1`". And about `vmarginratio`: "vertical margin ratio of top to bottom. The default ratio is 2:3". So, `vcentering` is about equating the top and bottom margins. By the way, in your test document, the `vcentering=true` option is overridden by the subsequent `margin=2cm` option. Of course, `margin=2cm` also equates the top and bottom margins.

Comment: Yea, as I came to discover, it doesn't vertically centre the header, but rather, the text box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the header block (height: `\headheight`) vertically within the top margin, you may want to run the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    margin=2cm,
    headsep=\dimexpr1cm-0.5\headheight\relax,
    showframe % optional
}
```

This solution works by treating `headsep` as a quantity that's determined by `tmargin` (here: 2cm) and `\headheight`. The `\headheight` length variable can be adjusted as well, of course; e.g., set `headheight=\baselineskip,` before running `headsep=\dimexpr1cm-0.5\headheight\relax,`.

I've omitted the option `vcentering=true` that was in your code for two reasons: First, it's overridden by `margin=2cm`. Second, it doesn't achieve what you're looking to get done.